# display data based on tag from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am making a page where the data will be shown as per `#tag` value from multiple tables.
Like 4 tables `Books, Articles, Authors & Categories`. All tables have the different field names but some filed names are common like (id, name, tags)

I am using the below query where it is showing the data from one table only.

```
$tag = 'compu';
SELECT * from books WHERE tags like '%".$tag."%' order by id
```

Please guide me how to show the data from multiple tables as per shown below:

**Required Result**

> 1. Type: book (Computing Tricks)
> 2. Type: book (Computing Formulas)
> 3. Type: article (Computer Structure)
> 4. Type: book (Computing Fakes)
> 5. Type: article (Computer Parts)
> 6. Type: category (Computing)
> 7. Type: author (Ahmad Computer Master)

**Articles Table:**

[image]

**Categories Table:**

[image]

**Authors Table:**

[image]

**Books Table:**

[image]

Comment: Please share the schema of the tables you intend to load data from.

Comment: Use joins to select from multiple tables at once.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I believe he needs union, but in order to write an answer we need to be sure about the structure of the tables involved.

Comment: @LajosArpad Somebody said, Unions make multiple selects just look like one. Also doing a query for each table is possible, too. So many ways. But as you said, without concrete structure it is hard to tell what is best.

Comment: @LajosArpad how to upload image here?

Comment: @usman610 there is a picture icon at the vertical top of your post box if you click on the Edit button. You can use that.

Comment: @LajosArpad done updated the question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between the schemas you have presented in your question. So, let's find out what columns you need. To me it seems that you need only some name, I will assume it's `aname`. If this is not the data you need, you can adjust the code below:

Categories, Articles, Authors, Books

```
select concat('Type: ', typename, '(', aname, ')')  as result
from (
    (select 'Category' as typename, aname from Categories)
    union
    (select 'Article' as typename, aname from Articles)
    union
    (select 'Author' as typename, aname from Authors)
    union
    (select 'Book' as typename, aname from Books)
) t
```

Code is untested, if there is a typo, let me know!

The indexes can be added to the result when you loop it. You should make sure thought that you protect yourself and your code against SQL injection.